# SQL - How to find the closest date match for each record from two tables without matching the same date for 2 rows

Tags: sql, database, date

Suppose I have `Table1` and `Table2` with the below data. I want to find the next closest date match for `JoiningDt` (column of `Table1`) that is available in `Table2` column `ClosestDt` for each `ID`. Note: Closest match from `Table2` should be greater than the the date of `Table1` and no two `ID`s can have the same closest match, e.g. `ID` 2 should take the value 08-Apr-2024 even though 07-Apr-2024 is the nearest one because it is already taken by `ID` 1.

Table1:

| ID | JoiningDt | DocNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 05-Apr-2024 | A123 |
| 2 | 06-Apr-2024 | A123 |
| 3 | 04-Apr-2024 | B123 |

Table2:

| DocNum | ClosestDt |
| --- | --- |
| A123 | 03-Apr-2024 |
| A123 | 04-Apr-2024 |
| A123 | 07-Apr-2024 |
| A123 | 08-Apr-2024 |
| B123 | 02-Apr-2024 |
| B123 | 05-Apr-2024 |

My Expected output is:

| ID | JoiningDt | DocNum | ClosestDt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 05-Apr-2024 | A123 | 07-Apr-2024 |
| 2 | 06-Apr-2024 | A123 | 08-Apr-2024 |
| 3 | 04-Apr-2024 | B123 | 05-Apr-2024 |

When I tried an left outer join, I get:

| ID | JoiningDt | DocNum | ClosestDt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-04-05 | A123 | 2024-04-07 |
| 1 | 2024-04-05 | A123 | 2024-04-08 |
| 2 | 2024-04-06 | A123 | 2024-04-07 |
| 2 | 2024-04-06 | A123 | 2024-04-08 |
| 3 | 2024-04-04 | B123 | 2024-04-05 |

```sql
select t1.ID
      ,t1.JoiningDt
      ,t1.DocNum
      ,(t2.ClosestDt)
 from #Table1 t1
 left join #Table2 t2
   on t1.DocNum = t2.DocNum and t2.ClosestDt > t1.JoiningDt
```

I tried using rownum also but the challenging part is getting the next match, i.e. 8-apr and not 7-apr, for `ID` 2 because 07-Apr is already taken by `ID` 1. Please assist.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: What is the data type of column `JoiningDt` (in `Table1`) and column `ClosestDt` (in `Table2`) ?

Answer (score 0):

This query ensures each "joining date" has a unique next "closest date" match.

Query:

```
WITH
  table_a AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `optimal-weft-418017.78206957.78206957_01` ),
  table_b AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `optimal-weft-418017.78206957.78206957_02`
  ORDER BY
    docnum,
    ClosestDt ),
  merged AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    JoiningDt,
    a.DocNum,
    ClosestDt
  FROM
    table_a a
  LEFT JOIN
    table_b b
  ON
    JoiningDt<ClosestDt
    AND a.docnum=b.docnum ),
  filtered AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, docnum ORDER BY JoiningDt) ROW
  FROM
    merged
  ORDER BY
    id,
    docnum,
    JoiningDt ),
  unique_docnum AS (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT id,
    joiningdt,
    docnum
  FROM
    filtered ),
  filtered_rows AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY docnum ORDER BY joiningdt) AS ROW
  FROM
    unique_docnum ),
  final AS (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT a.id,
    a.joiningdt,
    a.docnum,
    a.closestdt
  FROM
    filtered a
  INNER JOIN
    filtered_rows b
  ON
    a.row=b.row
    AND a.docnum=b.docnum
    AND a.id=b.id)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  final
ORDER BY
  id
```